# React updating data of an array but changes not appears

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a array of groups which is brought from API, and is displayed on a table..

```
return(
  <Table
     data={props.data}
    columns={columns}
    noHeader={true}
   />
)

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: state.Table.arrayGroups,
})
```

In this table I have a column that has a button that enable and disable a group, that calls this action:

```
 export const handleStatus = (data, status, id, endPoint, ActionType) => {

        let index = data.findIndex( array => array.id === id);

        console.log(index)
        if (status) {
            console.log('entrei disable')
            data[index].enable = false
            console.log(data)
            return dispatch => {
                httpPut(`${endPoint}/${id}/disable`)
                    .then(resp => {
                        return [
                            dispatch({
                                type: ActionType,
                                payload: data
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('entrei enable')
            data[index].enable = true
            return dispatch => {
                httpPut(`${endPoint}/${id}/enable`)
                    .then(resp => {
                        return [
                            dispatch({
                                type: ActionType,
                                payload: data
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

On this action I'm basically getting data array and changing a value inside of it.. and update the arrayGroups.. like this :

```
case 'MODIFIED_GROUPS':
            return { ...state, arrayGroups: action.payload }
```

**the issue is : after doing it table continuous displaying the previous array Data**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect by react-redux is a PureComponent . What it means is that unless the props change it doesn't trigger a re-render. And it performs a shallow equality and reference check.

Since in your case you are mutating the data, the update isn't triggereing.

Clone the data obejct and update it

```
 export const handleStatus = (data, status, id, endPoint, ActionType) => {

        let index = data.findIndex( array => array.id === id);

        console.log(index)
        const newData = [...data]; // shallow cloning data
        if (status) {
            console.log('entrei disable')
            newData[index].enable = false
            console.log(newData);
            return dispatch => {
                httpPut(`${endPoint}/${id}/disable`)
                    .then(resp => {
                        return [
                            dispatch({
                                type: ActionType,
                                payload: newData
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('entrei enable')
            newData[index].enable = true
            return dispatch => {
                httpPut(`${endPoint}/${id}/enable`)
                    .then(resp => {
                        return [
                            dispatch({
                                type: ActionType,
                                payload: newData
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :D